# differentiate between positive and negative sentence

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I have set of doctors opinions about patients that may or may not have certain disses.

lets say a doctor opinion about patient A is:

> The patient does not show sign of ms

or

> No focal or epileptiform features were noted

and for patient B is

> the patient show signs of ms

or

> complex partial seizures

I want to categorize A as ill but not B.

Is it possible using `NLTK` lib?

I tried to extract tags of the sentence using following code, but don't know were to go from here!

```
text = 'No focal or epileptiform features were noted'
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
print(tagged)

[('No', 'DT'), ('focal', 'JJ'), ('or', 'CC'), ('epileptiform', 'JJ'), ('features', 'NNS'), ('were', 'VBD'), ('noted', 'VBN')]
```

Comment: Do you have a collection of examples of each category? How big is it? What will you be using this code for?

Comment: 1- I got a list of disses and keywords related to it.2- 15000 text files (one for each patient) each ~10 kB. 3- Find out what disses each patient has based on content of the text file.

Comment: I think there are 2 options. 1. you have to tag the data with pos or neg and apply ML classifier.  2. look for the keywords for the diseases and negations -  basically pattern and apply rule based mechanism to classify it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are familiar with ML. Use the same technique as spam detection and create a set of limiting words. then apply it to your text files and suggest a label for each one as pos or neg. you may take a look at this: https://towardsdatascience.com/spam-classifier-in-python-from-scratch-27a98ddd8e73

Answer (score 0):

As [nag suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56882778/differentiate-between-positive-and-negative-sentence?noredirect=1#comment100343461_56882778), you can either create a rule-based system based on your keywords and phrases indicating negation or you can try to train a supervised statistical model to predict the class (positive or negative for a given disease).

I would also encourage you to be extremely careful with how you use the resulting system, since poor predictions can have a huge impact on peoples lives in the medical domain.